# LibGDX/Java - Trying to find the vector from one object to another

Tags: java, vector, graphics, libgdx, 2d

I want to add springs in my game that work like the ones in sonic - i.e. if you can't get over an obstacle you have to hit a spring which sends the main character flying towards another spring that gets him over that obstacle. I drew a little diagram below to demonstrate what I mean (yellow arrows represent the direction the player will go towards and the red - are the springs).
[image]

In my Spring class I have created a method:

```
//The detection area (blue rectangle in the diagram)
public Rectangle broadPhaseDetection() {
        broadPhaseRectangle = new Rectangle(getxPos() - broadPhaseLength, getyPos(),
        broadPhaseLength, broadPhaseLength);
        return broadPhaseRectangle;
    }
```

If the Player collides with a Spring, I check to see if there's ANOTHER Spring within the blue area and if there is - calculate the vector that takes you towards that spring and send the player in that direction.

This seems like a very simple concept which has probably been done loads of times before, but I couldn't find any good examples online for some reason. Does anybody know how I can get the vector I need?

Any insight is highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the position vector of the spring you hit is `Vector2 v1`, and the position of the second spring is `Vector2 v2`, then you just need `v2.sub(v1)`.

If you are only interested in the direction rather than the length of the vector, you might want to normalize by doing `v2.sub(v1).nor()` (this gives you a vector pointing the right way, but with length 1)

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the destination from the source to get the vector between them.  The vector from PointA to PointB is: PointB - PointA.  (And to subtract two vectors, just subtract their components.)

In Libgdx a `Vector2` can be used to track these, and it supports overloaded `sub` methods.